# Inserting PHP variable inside HTML tag, which is inside PHP function

Tags: php

I feel pretty stupid for asking this one, I want to paste 'id' that I retrieve from database, which is stored in $link variable into the `<a href>` tag after `details=...>Read More.`., but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<p>
    <?php 

    $longString = $row['name'];
    $link = $row['id'];

    echo readMoreHelper($longString);

    function readMoreHelper($story_desc, $chars = 100) {
        $story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,$chars);  
        $story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,strrpos($story_desc,' '));  
        $story_desc = $story_desc." <a href='details.php?details=$link>Read More...</a>";  
        return $story_desc;  
    } 

    ?> 
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `$link` as a function parameter.

You also left out the `'` at the end of the `href` attribute.

```
echo readMoreHelper($longString, $link);

function readMoreHelper($story_desc, $link, $chars = 100) {
    $story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,$chars);  
    $story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,strrpos($story_desc,' '));  
    $story_desc .= " <a href='details.php?details=$link'>Read More...</a>";  
    return $story_desc;  
}
```

Comment: thanks, I guess it's bed time since I failed to solve this one on my own.

Comment: @user14584183 If it's a good answer check it solve.

Comment: Ok! I doesn't have ask a question yet.  Happy coding!